# ActiveRecord does not work on App Engine - What's the alternative?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-app-engine, activerecord, jruby

Early reports of JRuby on Google App Engine indicate that **ActiveRecord does not work**.

It was my understanding that this was the only way to talk to the database in Rails.

Is this not the case? And, if not, **what is the alternative**?

Is there a more direct way in Rails of interfacing with Google's BigTable datastore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** Looks like somebody created a [sample JRuby-Rails application](http://jruby-rack.appspot.com/) - this should be an easy starting point.  Sample code is [here](http://github.com/nicksieger/jruby-rack/tree/master/examples/rails).

It appears that there are a few projects being worked on to create App Engine adapters for the [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org) ORM.  [This one](http://blog.s21g.com/articles/1426) should work with the current version of DataMapper (0.9.11), and [this one](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-jruby/) requires the 0.10.0 version in development.  They're both pretty new (to be expected, given how recently the App Engine Java announcement was made), so I can't vouch for their current quality, of course.

Using DataMapper with Rails requires a bit of extra configuration; see [this blog post](http://blog.teksol.info/2008/10/16/how-to-use-datamapper-from-rails-including-migrations-and-tests) for more information.  This will be made less onerous by Rails 3, which is intended to be ORM agnostic after the merge with Merb. If Rails 2.3 + DataMapper presents problems, one can also consider other Ruby web frameworks ([Merb](http://merbivore.com), [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/), etc.).

[This library](http://github.com/knowtheory/reggae/tree/master) may also prove helpful in setting up a JRuby web app on GAE.  I haven't tested any of these out, so YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

Try using JRuby on Rails: http://olabini.com/blog/2009/04/jruby-on-rails-on-google-app-engine/